# Probability of drawing cards with a certain property from a hand

Tags: probability

This question is inspired by a videogame called Slay the Spire, and me trying to calculate the optimum line to take. At first I thought it was just an n choose k problem, but that's not quite it. I'm missing something.

There are 6 attacking cards in my deck, and 4 defensive cards. Each turn you draw 5 cards, and on the particular turn I'm about to have the deck will shuffle, so my next 5 card hand will be a completely random draw from my 10 card deck. I've worked out that drawing *3 or more attacking cards* in my 5 card hand leads to a favourable outcome. I just want to know what the probability of that is.

10 choose 5 = 252 which is the number of possible hands. There are 6 attacks and 4 defends. I know there's a way of putting those facts together to get the % chance of drawing 3 or more attacks. I just can't quite get there.

I apologise if this is really basic...

Comment: If you draw $a+d$ cards then there are $\binom6a\binom4d$ ways to draw $a$ attacking and $d$ defensive cards. So find these numbers for $(a,d)=(3,2),(4,1),(5,0)$ and take the summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are fewer defensive cards, it’s slightly easier to calculate the probability of the complementary event of drawing $3$ or more defensive cards. This is

$$
\frac{\binom62\binom43+\binom61\binom44}{\binom{10}5}=\frac{11}{42}\;,
$$

since you can either draw $2$ attacking cards and $3$ defensive cards or $1$ attacking card and $4$ defensive cards. So the probability of drawing $3$ or more attacking cards is

$$
1-\frac{11}{42}=\frac{31}{42}\approx0.738\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm still struggling a bit to intuit why the number of ways to draw 2 attacks and 3 defends is (6 choose 2)*(4 choose 3). Could you expand on why that is the case?

Comment: @Jack: You have $6$ attacks and $4$ defends. There are $\binom62$ ways to choose $2$ of the $6$ attacks and $\binom43$ ways to choose $3$ of the $4$ defends. Each choice of attacks can be combined with each choice of defends, so the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) applies, so these counts need to be multiplied.

Comment: Ok yep I think that makes sense to me now. Appreciate the help